# Core Data and 'like' functionality between entities

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm about to implement a ***like*** functionality between a `User` entity and some other entity, such that User A can *like* an entity X. However, I'm not sure how to best implement this in Core Data.

There are two main points I need to consider:

- Adding another *likeable* entity should be trivial
- There needs to be a way to sync a `Like` that has been performed offline

My initial thought was to create an **abstract** Core Data entity `Like`.

A `User` has a to-many relationship with `Like`, and a `Like` has one `User`.

Then for each entity that should be *likeable*, I create a subclass of `Like` that has a to-one relationship to the *likeable* entity. The relationship to the `User` is inherited.

This way, the abstract entity `Like` can have attributes such as "syncedAt" and "deletedAt" so that it's possible to find out if a `Like` type entity has been synced to the server or not.

Does this sound reasonable or are there better ways to solve this problem in Core Data? Are there disadvantages to this design that I'm not foreseeing?

Answer (score 0):

why not have a parent entity `LikableEntity` which your likable entityies inherit from: this could have the `synchedAt` attributes. The your User has a to-many relationship `likedEntities` which contains anything it has liked

Comment: I've thought about this as well. But there are some issues. I won't know what's unsynced with the entity, i.e. which specific 'like' that needs to be POSTed to the server. And also, the likable entities may already be inheriting from another class that should not be likable.

Comment: I think you could use a predicate for the first one: synchedAt == nil (or is older than some stale timeout)? For the second if you had your other class as the root, the LikableEntity inherits from it, then your class inherits from LikableEntity. So the root class is not likeable, but your class is?

Comment: Using a predicate still doesn't solve the case in knowing exactly what changed and what needs syncing, did the object change or did some relationship to it change etc? And letting the LikableEntity inherit from some other entity seems a bit icky. What if I need to make another likeable that inherits from some other entity?

Comment: yeah i agree its not great having multiple entities in the inheritance, was just trying to think of alternatives to a proxy type entity. for the first one you would need to implement that logic anyway wouldnt you?

Comment: Making the 'like' a proxy type entity is a bit awkward, I agree. But it seems like the easiest way to later keep track of syncing. Maybe the benefits of making it a proxy type object outweighs the cost of a cleaner, direct relationship-type.

Comment: yeah i think the way you described in the question is probably the best way to go, its not great but has potential to get nasty if you go with sub entities